# Making a 2d player look at the cursor, and then move towards it

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Tweekable move speed
    public float MoveSpeed = 4;

    // Set what distance it should be from the target
    int MaxDist = 10;
    int MinDist = 5;

    // This is the target
    public Transform Mouse;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Keep looking at an object
        transform.LookAt();

     // Turn off gravity
    Physics2D.gravity = Vector2.zero;

    // When distance is over minimun
    if (Vector3.Distance(Mouse.position, Mouse.position) >= MinDist)
    {
        // Keep distance
        transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // When it's between max and minimun
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Mouse.position) <= MaxDist)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

// I imported this code from another project so the enemy keeps looking at the player, and keeps his distance. it was a 3D project, so there may be more errors, and this is also my first time creating a game. Be gentle

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that in order for anyone here to attempt to answer your question *you actually have to ask a question*. You can begin with what the problem is with your code, why are you asking for help? What did you expect it to do? What did you observe it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project right now.
Here is the code I use to rotate the player (first part) and then move it into that direction (second part):

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed;

void Update()
{ 
   //get mouse position
   Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
   //calculating the angle
   float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y - transform.position.y, mousePos.x - 
   transform.position.x);
   float AngleDeg = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;
   //rotating the player
   Player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, AngleDeg);

   //second part
   Vector3 mouseDir = mousePos - transform.position;
   mouseDir.z = 0f;
   mouseDir = mouseDir.normalized;
   rb.AddForce(mouseDir * speed);
}
```

If the player rotates, but it is looking in the wrong way (in my case), then play around with the the last line of the first part. The following code worked fine for me:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, AngleDeg - 90);
```

If you want the player to move at a constant speed, then you can use

```
rb.velocity = mouseDir * speed;
```

instead of

```
rb.AddForce(mouseDir * speed);
```

in the last line of the second part.

Your Player-Gameobject needs a Rigidbody2D component. I also added an if-statement around the second part, so the player only moves to the wanted direction when (for example) space is pressed, but always looks to the mouse.